Using Poincare-Bendixson to show there is a periodic orbit
I am having difficulty using Poincare-Bendixson to show that a particular system of differential equations has a periodic orbit. The system is
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x} & = & -3y+x(1-x^2-y^2+y)
\\
\dot{y} & = & \phantom{-}2x+y(1-x^2-y^2-4x)
\end{array}\right.
$$
Now, the expression $1-x^2-y^2$ made me investigate the unit circle:

However, I found that some solutions enter through the unit circle while others leave it, so it wasn't a useful "boundary".
So, more generally, I converted to polar and consider the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$.
I was able to verify that for sufficiently large $r$, no solutions leave through the circle of radius $r$ (i.e. $\dot{r}<0$).
Thus, any solution starting in the circle of radius $r$
remains in it.
Thus, if I take a solution starting within this circle, I can consider its forward $\omega$-limit set, which will be nonempty, compact, and connected.
The issue is that there is at least one fixed point within this circle (at the origin) and there could be more. - I am not sure how to find the fixed points and argue that there is a solution not converging to any of them in forward time.

Any ideas $?$.

It is also not too hard to show that for sufficiently small $r$, $\dot{r}>0$, so there is a bounded trapping region away from the origin. However, plotting seems to indicate that there are two more critical points in this region: one saddle point and one stable.

@whpowell96 I see, that makes sense. Then I suppose all that is left is to figure out how to deal with the other equilibria.
